# Fastest way to replicate a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

I'm looking for the fastest to replicate a data.frame. Is there `rep.data.frame` that replicates rows? and what is the fastest way to achieve this for all inputs? as I have a function that needs to replicate an object `x` that can be a `vector` or a `data.frame`.

The code I'm currently using

```r
repx <- function(x, ...) if(is.atomic(x)) rep(x, ...) else x[rep(1:nrow(x), ...),]
```

I used @ronak's answer to come up with a close enough solution although what I aim to achieve is to have a similar output to that of rep see output below:

```
rep.data.frame <- function(x, each, times) rbindlist(replicate(times, rbindlist(replicate(each, x, simplify = F) ), simplify = F) )

rep(data.frame(y=1:2), times=3, each=2)
    y
 1: 1
 2: 2
 3: 1
 4: 2
 5: 1
 6: 2
 7: 1
 8: 2
 9: 1
10: 2
11: 1
12: 2

# Desired output
    x
 1: 1
 2: 1
 3: 2
 4: 2
 5: 1
 6: 1
 7: 2
 8: 2
 9: 1
10: 1
11: 2
12: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple function that will repeat the rows of a `data.frame` or vector equal to the number of times specified (this is in fact very similar to what you are already doing. Note I couldn't get the `rep.data.frame` to give your desired output). A simple function could look like this:

```
rep_rows <- function(x, times) {
  if (is.matrix(x) | is.data.frame(x)) {
    x[rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), each = times), , drop = FALSE]
  } else {
    x[rep(seq_len(length(x)), each = times)]
  }
}
```

Let's create two objects to test the code:

```
db <- data.frame(
  y = rep(1:2, times = 3)
)

y <- rep(1:2, times = 3)
```

`db` looks like this:

```
> db
  y
1 1
2 2
3 1
4 2
5 1
6 2
```

and `y` looks like this:

```
> y
[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Using our function, we get:

```
> rep_rows(db, 2)
    y
1   1
1.1 1
2   2
2.1 2
3   1
3.1 1
4   2
4.1 2
5   1
5.1 1
6   2
6.1 2
>
```

and

```
> rep_rows(y, 2)
 [1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
```

EDIT:
Which when benchmarked on larger data is still quite quick. Curios to see how it compares to other approaches.

```
> db <- data.frame(
+   y = rep(1:5, times = 1000)
+ )
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(rep_rows(db, 100))
Unit: milliseconds
              expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 rep_rows(db, 100) 259.0079 279.6223 294.129 285.9272 307.0718 349.6123   100
```